# How can i display cart page in separate tab in php?

Tags: php

Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple PHP Shopping Cart</TITLE>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="shopping-cart">
<div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart <a id="btnEmpty" href="index.php?action=empty">Empty Cart</a></div>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $item_total = 0;
?>  
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th><strong>Action</strong></th>
</tr>   
<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $item["code"]; ?></td>
                <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>"></td>
                <td align=right><?php echo "$".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>    

  <?php
}
?>
<div class="checkout"> <a href="checkout.php?action=empty">Checkout</a></div>   

</div>

<div id="product-grid">
    <div class="txt-heading">Products</div>
    <?php
    $product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct ORDER BY id ASC");
    if (!empty($product_array)) { 
        foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
    ?>
        <div class="product-item">
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>"></div>
            <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
            }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now page look like this; http://s1.postimg.org/7yyj0rh1b/Untitled_1_copy.png

I need to display another tab for displaying shopping cart.

May i know, how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just wanting to be able to add another item row? Or you want that a whole other display section like the portion you circled?

Comment: @Rasclatt: I need to display only all the products in index page.. and when i  click the add to cart button, it links to another tab which is have show shopping cart page. thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by a tab? Are you wanting click to reload the page and that page would only display the cart, not all the other products as well?

Comment: If i click the add to cart button under the product, it need to show separate page that shopping cart.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I read your instructions correctly, and I am not 100% sure I am, I think you want to only display the cart on add. To do this I think I would break your page up into parts so that each portion has a task. then you can more easily separate out your cart from your all-products display. You can also more-easily use the cart on other parts of the site since it is a class:

**class.ShoppingCart.php**

```
<?php
class ShoppingCart
    {
        protected   $db;

        public  function __construct($db)
            {
                $this->db   =   $db;
            }

        public  function execute()
            {
                if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
                        switch($_GET["action"]) {
                            case "add":
                                $this->AddToCart();
                                break;
                            case "remove":
                                $this->RemoveFromCart();
                                break;
                            case "empty":
                                $this->EmptyCart();
                                break;  
                        }
                    }
            }

        public  function AddToCart()
            {
                // I don't know if code is supposed to be numeric or not and I also
                // don't know if you sanitize your input, but from just looking at this
                // it looks dangerous (sql injection-prone)
                if(!empty($_POST["quantity"]) && is_numeric($_GET["code"])) {
                    $productByCode  =   $this->db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
                    $itemArray      =   array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

                    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                        if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                                    if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                            }
                        } else {
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                    }
                }
            }

        public  function RemoveFromCart()
            {           
                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                    }
                }
            }

        public  function EmptyCart()
            {
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }

        public  function DisplayCart()
            {
                if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"]) && !empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                        $item_total = 0; ?>

    <div id="shopping-cart">
        <div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart <a id="btnEmpty" href="index.php?action=empty">Empty Cart</a></div>
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Action</strong></th>
                    </tr><?php       
                                foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></strong></td>
                        <td><?php echo $item["code"]; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>"></td>
                        <td align=right><?php echo "$".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
                    </tr>
                        <?php
                                    $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
                                } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        <div class="checkout"> <a href="checkout.php?action=empty">Checkout</a></div>   
    </div>   
  <?php             }
            }
    } ?>
```

**/includes/products/index.php**

```
<?php 
// Exit if the database is not set
// Stops direct access to this file
if(!isset($db_handle)) return; ?>
<div id="product-grid">
    <div class="txt-heading">Products</div>
    <?php
    $product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct ORDER BY id ASC");
    if (!empty($product_array)) { 
        foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
    ?>
        <div class="product-item">
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>"></div>
            <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
            }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
// Include shopping cart class
require_once("class.ShoppingCart.php");
// Initiate db instance
$db_handle      =   new DBController();
// Initiate shopping cart engine
$ShoppingCart   =   new ShoppingCart($db_handle);
// Execute the engine portion that handles adding/removing/emptying
$ShoppingCart->execute(); ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple PHP Shopping Cart</TITLE>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
    // If adding to the cart, show the cart
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'add')
        $ShoppingCart->DisplayCart();
    // Only show product page if action add not available
    else
        include('includes/products/index.php'); ?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: sorry, your answer is not working, when i click the add to cart button, it didn't add product for cart section. and it didn't work for separate page.. thanks..

Comment: The code is the same as yours except 1) it's presented a bit differently, and 2) there are extra checks where noted. If those extra checks are not needed, you can remove them. I put them in because in some spots there is no validation of input. Also, based on the description that I could glean, it should work based on the add action. If the action is add, it will show the cart, else shows the rest of the products. That part is pretty straight forward.